# Laravel routing different in two ambients

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 ambients, one for Local development (in Ubuntu for Windows 10), where I run my server with`php artisan serve --port=123` and I access through `http://127.0.0.1:123/` and another one in a shared host called Dev, where I access to through this URL: `http://dev.example.com/my_project/public/`

In my routes I have this:

```
Route::redirect('/', '/inicio', 301);
Route::get('inicio', 'DashboardController@index')->name('inicio');
```

In Local, when I access to `http://127.0.0.1:123/` it redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:123/inicio` which is correct. But in Dev if I join to `http://dev.example.com/my_project/public/` it redirects to `http://desa.laravel.com/inicio` Why is happening that?. Plus, in Local and in Dev, if I use: href="{{ route('inicio') }}"> both sites sends me to where I need, which is `http://127.0.0.1:123/inicio` and `http://dev.example.com/my_project/public/inicio` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your web root to the public folder.

Laravel can work in different directories, but truth be told you will have a very difficult time getting Laravel to work perfectly in other ways.

Comment: I see... that's the same that I've read in other forums, chats, FB groups, etc. So, I'll have to ask that we need subdomains, for example `http://my_project.dev.example.com/`